# Android - Dynamic scrollview size to use remaining space

Tags: android, scrollview

EDITED to improve specifics:

Hi, my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Select Character"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SelectedCharacterName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TraitName1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Trait 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        etc...

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Character1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4a4a4a"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Character 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            etc...

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonConfirmCharacter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/button_Confirm" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am looking to make the scrollview fit the remaining space between the other elements however with this setup the scrollview doesn't seem to render at all. These settings are the result of looking for solutions and implementing weight.

An answer without java code would be preferential.

Thanks.

Comment: look for the layout_weight property of the LinearLayout

Comment: was using weight but wouldnt work, edited to include xml

Comment: remove the weight from all the elements but the scrollview. It should be have weight 1 and height 0dip

Answer (score 0):

Here, this would works just fine

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text1" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SelectedCharacterName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TraitName1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Trait 1" />

        etc...

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Character1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Character 1" />

                etc...
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonConfirmCharacter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/button_Confirm" /></LinearLayout>
```